# Install Pgpool on a server different from the DB server

Tags: postgresql, server, psql, high-availability, pgpool

I have 3 server (PgPool-II installed) and 2 Db (PostgreSQL installed) server.

I followed https://www.pgpool.net/docs/43/en/html/example-cluster.html

But can't execute `psql template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgpool_recovery"`

What can i do?

Is it possible to install Postgresql and Pgpool on different servers in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Pgpool-II extension on the Postgresql machine to execute following command.

```
psql template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgpool_recovery"
```

see details here:
https://www.pgpool.net/docs/43/en/html/install-pgpool-recovery.html

And yes, its possible to have Pgpool-II and Postgresql on two different machines.